# Random Sequence sum divisibility

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $A_{1},A_{2}...A_{n}$ be a sequence then prove that there exists integers k and r such that the sum
$a_k+a_{k+1}+...+a_{k+r}$
is divisible by $n$ .
.can anyone help. Also i got that it's related to Erdos theorem (i don't know about it) .

Comment: All A1,A2 the no.s are subscript.

Comment: You are having issues typing the problem. Try to use MathJax to type the problem in. In this scenario, the least you can do is provide a link to the problem page. Nobody will be confident of answering your question until they understand it fully, and you have not unfortunately done your best in being clear. If you do that, it'd be nice.

Comment: Sorry but don't know how to use math Jax .isi bmath 2008 problem 4.(sequence of integers)

Comment: The sequence $0,1,3,8,9$, has $0$ which is a multiple of $5$, and also $3+8+9=20$ which is a multiple of $5$, and the sequence $0,-1,-2,-3$ has $0$ which is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: ISI BMath 2008 : Wherever I went I only found papers until $2015$. Worst come worst, take a screenshot and paste it. Once you do that, I will edit the MathJax of the question to give you an example of how it's done. Look, once you're set up on MathJax, it'll take you seconds to type a good question, and you will get better attention and better answers this way. We will definitely look into the question and your confusion if it is presented properly.

Comment: Maybe you are looking at problem $4$ from here : http://www.amitghosh.net/isi-bmath-2008-solutions/

Comment: Can't post pictures (less than 10 reputation) edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

$S_1$ =$a_1$ ,
$S_2$=$a_1+a_2$ , 
....
..
    $S_n$=$a_1+a_2+a_3+ .......+a_n$ , .
Then if we divide all the sums by n then there can be at most n remainders or n residual class components of the integer n. Then we will find a pair of conjugate residual classes and subtract both ($S_{i}–S_{j}$) which will be divisible by n . If there are not n distinct remainders then by subtracting the sum with the same remainders we will get a intermediate sum divisible by n. I think it may be a solution.
 $S_i$ =n.p+$r_1$       and.      $S_j$=n.q+$r_2$
We will select such sum with remainders that whose sum is n or subtract to get 0

Comment: Didn't saw that the answer matched with that in the link given . delete my answer if required.